# adding texture and wireframes in three-globe

Tags: javascript

I'm using three-globe to try to show movements on the globe. The regular line are tough to visualize if they overlap (due to lack of border), so was looking to draw as cylinders.  Thus far I've had no luck (see pic) and wonder if I'm calling the object correctly.

[image]

```
 const cylinderData = [...Array(N_cylinders).keys()].map(() => ({
  lat: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 180,
  lng: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 360,
  lat2: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 180,
  lng2: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 360,
  alt: path_altitude ,
  radius: Math.random() * 5,
  color: 'red'
  }));






.customLayerData(cylinderData )
.customThreeObject(d => {
  let pointX = Globe.getCoords(d.lat, d.lng, d.alt);
  let pointY = Globe.getCoords(d.lat2, d.lng2, d.alt);
  let direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(pointY, pointX);
 const  cylinder_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
  let edge_size =4;
 geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(edge_size , edge_size , direction.length(), 16, 14, true);
 
geometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, direction.length() / 2, 0));

geometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(90)));
    
let Edge_array = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,  cylinder_material );
Edge_array.position.copy (pointX);
Edge_array.lookAt(pointY); 
scene.add(Edge_array) ;
```